# how can I define a XSd Integer datatype with following restriction: the first digit should not be zero. (no zeros at the beginning)

Tags: regex, xsd

how can I define a XSd Integer datatype with following restriction: the first digit should not be zero. (no zeros at the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<xs:restriction>` element based on the `xs:integer` data type along with a `<xs:pattern>` facet like this:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:pattern value="[^0].*"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

This will let only values allowed by `xs:integer` be valid, with the additional restriction that the first character must not be a zero.

Note that the pattern in the `<xs:pattern>` element always refers to the whole value, so a beginning marker like `^` is not required.